# Convert column table to pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

I'm trying to reach data with pivot table results and how to convert the script below using with pivot command.

```
select 
count (escalated_by) as escalated_by,
count (resolved_by) as resolved_by,
count (respond_by) as respond_by,
count (return_by) as return_by,
count (transfer_by) as transfer_by
from dummytable
where reported_date between '2021-06-01' and '2021-06-28'
```

I want result like below.

[image: 1]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TSQL

```
select 
  report_this_week, 
  total 
from 
  (
    select 
      Count (escalated_by) as escalated_by, 
      Count (resolved_by) as resolved_by, 
      Count (respond_by) as respond_by, 
      Count (return_by) as return_by, 
      Count (transfer_by) as transfer_by 
    from 
      table 
    where 
      reported_date BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-28'
  ) as p 
unpivot(
    total for report_this_week in (
      escalated_by, resolved_by, respond_by, 
      return_by, transfer_by
    ) as x
```

Comment: Hi smpa01, is there any other script to use a single date?